# Write code in debug mode

Tags: r, debugging

Coming from MATLAB and learning R, I found it hard to not being able to add extra code in an interrupted "Debug Mode" session. When debugging a function in R, using for example `browser()`, I cannot seem to add code to my function. For that, I need to exit the Debug Mode and add extra code without being able to test it immediately in the Debug session.

Is there any way of achieving what is usually doable in MATLAB?

Comment: You can add code by entering it in the console when the breakpoint is hit. Or did I get your wrong? It's correct though that you cannot modify the function itself. (Can you do that in MATLAB?)

Comment: Yes, indeed: you can write code in the console in R. But this code is not saved when exiting debug mode, so one has to write it again after the debugging. In R, one can write this code in the original file, and save the updated function after debug mode is finished---but at least, the code is in the editor instead of the console...

Comment: Ah, I see. Instead of writing it again, maybe you can use the command `history()`. Although it's of course not perfect.